# Comparar dos fechas con PHP

Tags: php

Quisiera comparar dos fechas, pero no sólo con la información de año, mes y día, también con la hora.

Estoy probando con:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11 19:10');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13 18:23');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a días');
```

Me devuelve tan sólo el resultado en días, no las horas. ¿Hay alguna forma para que me indique la diferencia en días y horas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El metodo `format()` usa diferentes *modificadores* que permiten que el texto se reemplace en ellos dependiendo del valor que les indiques.

**¿Que quiere decir esto?**

En la linea donde haces:

```
echo $interval->format('%R%a días');
```

Estas haciendo que la funcion `format` reemplace *%R* y _%a% con los siguientes valores *(de acuerdo a la [documentacion](http://php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.format.php#refsect1-dateinterval.format-parameters) de PHP)*:

> R     Signo "-" cuando es negativo, "+" cuando es positivo
>
> a     Número total de días como resultado de una operación con DateTime::diff(), o de lo contrario (unknown)

Lo que falta incluir en el `format` son los modificadores, que te retornaran la diferencia en horas, minutos y segundos, *(de acuerdo a la [documentacion](http://php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.format.php#refsect1-dateinterval.format-parameters) de PHP)*:

> H  Horas, numérico, al menos 2 dígitos empezando con 0
>
> I  Minutos, numérico, al menos 2 dígitos empezando con 0
>
> S  Segundos, numérico, al menos 2 dígitos empezando con 0

**Dejando tu codigo asi:**

```
<?php

$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11 19:10:01');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13 20:11:05');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

echo $interval->format('%R%a días %H horas %I minutos %S segundos');

?>
```

*Resultado*

> +2 días 01 horas 01 minutos 04 segundos

Answer (score 0):

Realmente la variable `$interval` es un array en el que se almacenan la diferencia en años, meses, días, horas, etc...

Puedes ver todos los datos que se almacenan dentro de esa variable usando:

```
var_dump($interval);
```

Sin embargo, si solo quieres sacar la diferencia en días y horas puedes sacar por pantalla simplemente esos dos valores de la siguiente manera:

```
echo($interval->d . " dias");
echo($interval->h . " horas");
```

Te dejo la **[demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85cee8a9d3f6f4e907396c128a688fa12ea59186)** para que puedas ver el resultado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me ha sido de gran ayuda también, aunque considero en este caso que la respuesta de Ivan ha sido más exacta.

Answer (score 0):

Si solo quieres comparar las fechas sin la necesidad de conocer cual es la diferencia en días, horas, minutos y segundos te puede valer una comparación de dateTime:

```
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11 19:10');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-11 19:23');

if($datetime1 < $datetime2) {
    echo $datetime1->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')." es menor que ".$datetime2->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')."<br>";

} else if($datetime1 == $datetime2) {
    echo $datetime1->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')." es igual que ".$datetime2->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');

} else {
    echo $datetime1->format('d-m-Y H:i:s')." es mayor que ".$datetime2->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
}
```