# comprar dos fechas en una consulta php

Tags: php

**buen dia, necesito comparar dos fechas la actual con la que tengo en base de datos pero no lo he logrado hacer**, tiempo_o es la fecha que tengo en base de datos "date", y $fecha_actual ya es la fecha que me muestra que fecha es hoy.

```js
<?php

include '../bd/global.php';

date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');  

$fecha_actual = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $fecha_entrada = strtotime(tiempo_0);
        $query="select * from recargas_operador where tiempo_o = $fecha_actual  and id_operador=".$_GET['id_operador'];
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }else{
        $query="select * from recargas_operador where tiempo_o = $fecha_actual and id_operador=".$_GET['id_operador'];
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetchAll()); 
    }
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}

?>
```

// tambien intente esta forma para tampoco funciona, donde meti el campo tiempo_o dentro de "strtotime(date(tiempo_o))" pero igual no me funciona.

```js
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
         $query="select * from recargas_operador where  strtotime(date(tiempo_o)) = $fecha_actual  and id_operador=".$_GET['id_operador'];
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    }else{
        $query="select * from recargas_operador where strtotime(date(tiempo_o)) = $fecha_actual  and id_operador=".$_GET['id_operador'];
        $resultado=metodoGet($query);
        echo json_encode($resultado->fetchAll()); 
    }
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit();
}
```

// lo que necesito es poder comparar dos fechas, la primera $fecha_actual esa funciona bien pero la segunda fecha esta base de datos y esta en el campo "tiempo_o" pero si comparo $fecha_actual con tiempo_o el query no me puede comprar las dos fechas por que  tiempo_o  debe llevar una codificación como $fecha_actual para poder compararlas.

```js
 $query="select * from recargas_operador where  strtotime(date('tiempo_o')) = $fecha_actual  and id_operador=".$_GET['id_operador'];
```

Comment: Cuando comparas, ¿Qué resultado quieres obtener? En esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58065/comparar-dos-fechas-con-php?rq=1) puede que te ayude.

Comment: es que en  base de datos tengo registro de fecha de hoy y solo quiero mostrar esos registros por eso hago la comparación de la fecha de hoy con la fechas que tengo en base de datos.

Comment: Etiqueta el motor de base de datos que usas.

Comment: mysql, solo necesito que el campo que estoy cargando "tiempo_o" que esta en formato "date" en la base de datos lo pueda comprar con la variable $fecha_actual en mi query

Comment: Puedes comparar las variables de las 2 fechas con un `if`, y que si se cumplen, obtengas el resultado que deseas, es lo que yo entiendo

Comment: ¿La columna `tiempo_o` es del tipo `DATE` o del tipo `DATETIME`? ¿Muéstranos un pequeño set de datos de la tabla que incluya los valores de `tiempo_o`. Para la consulta SQL no necesitas hacer esto `strtotime(date('tiempo_o'))` si la columna es del tipo adecuado.