# Alertas de vencimiento PHP y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Alguien me podria orientar o corregir este dilema
Estoy manejando un sistema de certificaciones para empleados las cuales tienen una fecha de certificacion y otra de vencimiento las certificaciones caducan cada 3 meses por lo cual requiero que 2 dias antes me muestre una alerta de que esta por vencerse y otra que me muestre una alerta de que ya vencio el unico problema es que por empleado pueden llegar a tener hasta 15 certificaciones dejo el codigo que yo tengo hasta ahorita gracias.

```
$check = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT empleado.NoReloj,certificaciones.Fecha_Ven 
                    FROM empleado, certificaciones WHERE Fecha_Ven between curdate() and date_add(curdate(), interval 10 day)");

     $checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);
     if($checkrows){
        ?>
        <script>
        alert("Certificacion vencida");
        </script>
     <?php
     }
     else{
        ?>
        <script>
        alert("Certificacion por vencer");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

No se si estoy utilizando la consulta incorrecta o de plano esta mal o no se si se pueda mejor que en la tabla que me muesta al hacer la consulta a un lado de la certificacion me arroje el mensaje les anexo la ayuda visual de mi php

[image: Consulta de certificaciones]

Y este mi codigo php

````
$sql = ("SELECT empleado.NoReloj,certificaciones.Certificacion,certificaciones.Fecha_Cert,certificaciones.Fecha_Ven 
                    FROM empleado, certificaciones WHERE empleado.NoReloj='".$_REQUEST['matricula']."' AND certificaciones.empleado_id ='".$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");
    
    //realizamos la consulta para mostrar datos del empleado y la imagen
      $consulta2= ("SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE empleado.NoReloj='" .$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");
     $consuimg= ("SELECT Imagen FROM empleado WHERE empleado.NoReloj='" .$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");

     //variables
      $result2=mysqli_query($con,$consulta2);
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
     $resimg = mysqli_query($con,$consuimg);
     

    

    // row not found, do stuff...
     if($result2->num_rows == 0) {
          ?>
    <script>
    alert("No se encontro registro");
    window.location.href='./../work/consult.php';
    </script>
    <?php
     }


     if(mysqli_num_rows($result2)>0){
    
        if($datos=mysqli_fetch_row($result2)){
            $matricula2=$datos[0];
            $nombre2=$datos[2];
            $apellido1=$datos[3];
            $apellido2=$datos[4];
            $fecha=$datos[5];
            $area=$datos[6];
            
            
        }
     } 

     while($row = $resimg->fetch_assoc()){
        
        $image = './../img/'.$row["Imagen"];
     ?>

     <img src="<?php echo $image;?>" alt="" align="right"  />
     <?php }

      ?>

     <table align="center">
     <tr>
        <td>Numero de Reloj</td>
        <td>Area</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><input type="text" name="matricula" value="<?php echo $matricula2; ?>" disabled></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $area; ?>" disabled></td>
     </tr>
          <tr></tr>
     <tr></tr>
     <tr></tr>
     <tr></tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Nombre</td>
     <td>Apellido Paterno</td>
     <td>Apellido Materno</td>
     <td>Fecha Ingreso</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $nombre2; ?>" disabled></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $apellido1; ?>" disabled></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $apellido2; ?>" disabled></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $fecha; ?>" disabled></td>
    
     </tr>
    
     </table><br><br>
      <table border='1' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' align="center">
     <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;Certificacion&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;Fecha Certificacion&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;Fecha Vencimiento&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <form name="form1" method="post" action="">

     <?php
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     printf(
        "<tr><td>
        
        <input type='text' name='Certificacion' size='20'
         maxlength='30' value='%s' disabled></td><td>&nbsp;
    
        <input type='text'name='Fecha_Cert' size='20'
         maxlength='30' value='%s' disabled></td><td>&nbsp;
    
        <input type='text'name='Fecha_Ven' SIZE='20'
         MAXLENGTH='30' value='%s' disabled>&nbsp;
         
         </td></tr>",

          $row["Certificacion"],$row["Fecha_Cert"],$row["Fecha_Ven"]
     );
        
      }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    ?>
     </form>

     </table>

      ```
De antemano gracias
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo lo que haría es realizar un if validando si la fecha actual es igual a la de vencimiento del certificado. Además puedes realizar otro if que le reste 3 días a la fecha de vencimiento y la compare con la actual, para así avisarle 3 días antes.

El problema según yo, surge cuando estas certificaciones tienen una misma fecha de vencimiento y mas de alguna esta por vencer, por ende  si quieres mostrarle un alert o algo así, le saldrá por la cantidad de certificaciones que esten por vencer, una solución seria crear un array con los ID de certificaciones que están por vencer y luego mostrarle un mensaje tipo "Las certificaciones con ID 1, 2, 3 están apunto de vencer" aun que los alert hoy en día son un poco engorrosos, lo mejor seria, pintar la fila de un color, por ejemplo amarillo si faltan 3 días por vencer y rojo si ya esta totalmente vencida.

Todo esto lo puedes hacer comparando la fecha de vencimiento con la actual.

Comment: Hola me ayudo tu comentario mi pregunta ahora es puedo añadir un 3er if para que me de la opcion de certificacion vigente

Lo resolvi asi y si me muestra el vencimiento y cuantos dias le queda pero no me muestra la opcion vigente

Comment: $fecha_final = new DateTime($row['Fecha_Ven']);
     $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');

     // Si la fecha final es igual a la fecha actual o anterior
     if ($dias <= 0) {
     echo '<th>Certificacion vencida</th>';
     } 
     elseif($dias <= 2) {
     echo '<td>Está a ' . $dias . ' días de vencer</td>';
     }
     echo "</tr>";
        
      }

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes no se entiende mucho el codigo, sin embargo lo podrias controlar con fechas, comparando la fecha actual y la fecha de vencimiento, si ya caduco muestras tu mensaje, si faltan dos dias que ya va a caducar

Comment: Y como podria hacer la comparacion ?

Esta es la consulta que uso para que me muestre la tabla con los datos de certificacion fecha de certificacion y vencimiento 

$sql = ("SELECT empleado.NoReloj,certificaciones.Certificacion,certificaciones.Fecha_Cert,certificaciones.Fecha_Ven 
                 FROM empleado, certificaciones WHERE empleado.NoReloj='".$_REQUEST['matricula']."' AND certificaciones.empleado_id ='".$_REQUEST['matricula']."'");

Comment: Y ya me muestra la tabla que se aprecia en la imagen si lo hago como me dices de comparar me gustaria que me mostrara el mensaje en una columna nueva que diga estatus y ya ahi me muestre el mensaje de vencido o por vencer

Comment: <?php
$fecha_actual = strtotime(date("d-m-Y H:i:00",time()));
$fecha_entrada = strtotime("19-11-2008 21:00:00");

if($fecha_actual > $fecha_entrada){
        echo "La fecha entrada ya ha pasado";
}else{
        echo "Aun falta algun tiempo";
}
?>

Comment: aca hay algo mas avanzado que te puede ayudar para lo que falta dos dias:https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58065/comparar-dos-fechas-con-php

Comment: Okey eso si ya vi y consulte lo que me comentaste tu de codigo

Comment: Ahora solo mi duda es con una sola comparacion me serviria para todas las certificaicones que tiene un solo empleado ya tomando mis 2 fechas en la comparacion

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a ambos ya lo consegui la verdad no se si este bien echo de esta manera pero me funciono me muestra los 3 opciones siempre lo hice como me comentaron con un diff

Anexo el codigo

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Certificacion']."</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' >".$row['Fecha_Cert']."</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' >".$row['Fecha_Ven']."</td>";

     $fecha_final = new DateTime($row['Fecha_Ven']);
     $dias = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_final)->format('%r%a');

     // Si la fecha final es igual a la fecha actual o anterior
     if ($dias <=0) {
     echo '<td><font color="#FF0000">Certificacion Vencida</font></td>';
     } 
     elseif($dias <= 2) {
     echo '<td><Font color="#FF8C00"> Está a ' . $dias . ' días de vencer </FONT></td>';
     }
     if ($dias >=10){
        echo '<td><font color="#3CB371">Certificacion Vigente</font></td>';
     }
     echo "</tr>";
        
      }
```

[image: Gracias]